# Why does L2E choke when I try to use an interface in my Where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, set-theory

I have a LINQ to Entities query (using EF 4) that has some pretty complicated set-based filtering going on. The code compiles just fine, but when I try to run it, I get the following error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'ITextEntity'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Now for the code. I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface ITextEntity
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string TextValue { get; set; }
    EntityCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that these "Text Entities" represent lookup tables storing properties of `Product`. If Products have a color, all red Products will contain a Color entity with TextValue = "Red", and there will be a Color entity decorated with this interface:

```
public partial class Color : ITextEntity 
{ 
    //ID, TextValue, and Products implemented in EF-generated code
}
```

ITextEntities may have 1:N or N:N relationships back to `Product`.

I have a nested collection (actually a `List<IEnumerable<ITextEntity>>`) which contains sets of different entities implementing the `ITextEntity` interface. I want to use these sets to filter a sequence of `Product`s in a semi-inclusive fashion. Here's the code:

```
List<IEnumerable<ITextEntity>> InclusiveFilters;
IQueryable<Product> Products;

//...snip...

Products = Products.Where(prod => 
    InclusiveFilters.All(filter => 
        filter.Any(iTextEnt => 
            iTextEnt.Product.Contains(prod)
        )
    )
);
```

So what I'm trying to do is this:

> 1. I have a set, Products, that I want to filter.
> 2. For each of several types that implement `ITextEntity`, there's a
>      set S of entities of that type.
> 3. Each object O has a set O.P of products.
> 4. For each Product prod in Products, 
>            for each set S, 
>                for at least one O in S,
>                    O.P must contain prod. If not, remove prod from Products.

As you can see, this is pretty complicated.

I have the feeling that this is caused by LINQ not being able to work with the `ITextEntity` type, rather than a problem with my set operations. However, the complexity of the above is making this difficult to work with, and difficult to find a non-LINQ alternative. It's going to get pretty ugly if I can't use LINQ.

I found [an MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx) and a [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400100/linq-returns-list-or-single-object) discussing similar exceptions, but neither was much help. [Another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879411/entity-framework-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-closure-type) aims a finger at my use of the `Contains` method, but because of the complexity here, I haven't had much luck trying to replace it with the [BuildOrExpression](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx) method. I doubt BuildOrExpression will work anyway, since this is EF 4 and `Contains` is supposed to be supported.

So I'm rather stuck here. Can anyone advise?

**EDIT**: This question was answered in Aug 2010, but I've come back to clean up the title and description.

Comment: The problem isn't `Contains`. It appears to be in `InclusiveFilters.All`. That's your code, I guess, but you don't show it.

Comment: Sorry, can you please clarify what you mean by "That's your code, I guess, but you don't show it"? `InclusiveFilters.All` is the `IEnumerable<T>.All` extension method.

Comment: `InclusiveFilters` looked like a type in your post. But I now see it's a capitalized var. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're implicitly casting to `ITextEntity`. But `ITextEntity` is not part of your entity data model, so the EF doesn't know how to translate its members into SQL. `Contains` is supported, but only with primitive or entity types. Also, you use `IEnumerable`, which also prevents translation to SQL; you need `IQueryable` to be convertable to SQL.

So if you remove the interface reference and `IEnumerable`, you should be able to execute the query on the DB server. Otherwise you have to go into L2O (with, e.g., `AsEnumerable()`).

Comment: So to remove the interface, you're thinking, for example, something like `filter.Any(iTextEnt => iTextEnt.Product.Select(p => p.ID).Contains(prod.ID))`? That one works in L2O, but not in L2E. I understand what you mean by plugging in a primitive type rather than an interface, but I'm not quite sure how to get it done in a way L2E will be able to translate.

Comment: The problem is `InclusiveFilters`. Since it has `ITextEntity` in its type, it can't be used in L2E (mostly, certainly not when you get this error). All references to this type, direct or indirect, must be removed from the query.

Comment: Update: I think I figured it out, though I haven't yet verified that it's getting processed to the DB server. If so, that will be outstanding. Thanks for your help.