# error in LINQ query using two contexts on Constant Value Type

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am getting the following error from the query below;

```
 Unable to create a constant value of type 'tradedata.symbol'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

Note: The query is broken up in two as I cannot query two seperate contexts and I cant join symbolIdList to the projections list in LINQ as its an object in memeory so I put projList in memory so both objects would be in memory.

```
Public Function FillRangeProjDropdown(ByRef ddl As DropDownList, includeEquities As Boolean) As DropDownList

    Dim requestedDate As Date = MySqlDate(DateTime.Now.Date)
    Dim symbolTypeList As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {17, 18, 19})
    Dim symbolIdList As List(Of symbol)

    Using symbCtx As New SymbolsEntities()
        If Not includeEquities Then
            symbolIdList = (From d In symbCtx.symbols
                            Where symbolTypeList.Contains(d.SymbolType)
                            Select d).ToList()
        Else
            symbolIdList = (From d In symbCtx.symbols
                            Where d.SymbolType = 20
                            Select d).ToList()
        End If
    End Using

    Using projCtx As New ProjectionsEntities()
        Dim dvpList As New List(Of DataValuePair)
        Dim projList As List(Of projection) = (From d In projCtx.projections
                                               Where d.Date = requestedDate
                                               Select d).ToList()
        'symbolIdList is a collection of objects in memory and you cannot join a set of data in the database with another set of data that is in memory.
        dvpList = (From d In projList
                   Join e In symbolIdList On e.Id Equals d.SymbolId
                   Select New DataValuePair() With {
                       .Text = e.Name,
                       .Value = e.Id}).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(o) o.Text).ToList()

        For x As Integer = 1 To dvpList.Count
            ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem(dvpList(x - 1).Text, dvpList(x - 1).Value))
        Next
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select a Commodity", 0))

    End Using
    Return ddl
End Function
```

Comment: What data type is `symbol`? Is it a class you set up? Does it have an ID or some other unique scalar identifier? And can you step through the code in the debugger to narrow down where the problem is showing up? We don't need to see anything that doesn't touch `symbol`, or anything in an `If` block that isn't running.

Comment: it is a claas and yes it has an id. The error is generated dvpList= code  line. Stepping through the debugger doesnt help and , for me, neither did the generated error.

Comment: I meant step through the debugger to narrow down where the problem is. This is a lot of code, and most of it won't be relevant. It will be much easier to help you if we know when the problem happens.

Comment: Also, what version of EF are you using?

Comment: EF 6.1 and I said that the debugger errs on the dvpList = (From d In projList
                   Join e In symbolIdList On e.Id Equals d.SymbolId
                   Select New DataValuePair() With {...... code line with the error I put in the post

Comment: @dinotom: I somehow doubt that's the case. The way the code above is written, that line of code is not touching any EntityFramework contexts, so it's running in LINQ to Objects. Did you modify the code you posted, from what you're actually debugging against?

Comment: You cannot query two separate contexts so symbolIdList is created as a variable in memory and since you cannot join a memory object with a data base object in LINQ I had to create projList in memory as well so yes, no EF in the query itself now but thats where the error is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to have both context's variables in memory because you CANNOT query a database object when the other variable is in memory, in the current iteration, .Distinct() is not necessary, therefore removing .Distinct() solves the issue.

**Updated code**

```
Public Function FillRangeProjDropdown(ByRef ddl As DropDownList, includeEquities As Boolean) As DropDownList

    Dim requestedDate As Date = MySqlDate(DateTime.Now.Date)
    Dim symbolTypeList As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {17, 18, 19})
    Dim symbolIdList As List(Of symbol)

    Using symbCtx As New SymbolsEntities()
        If Not includeEquities Then
            symbolIdList = (From d In symbCtx.symbols
                            Where symbolTypeList.Contains(d.SymbolType)
                            Select d).ToList()
        Else
            symbolIdList = (From d In symbCtx.symbols
                            Where d.SymbolType = 20
                            Select d).ToList()
        End If
    End Using

    Using projCtx As New ProjectionsEntities()
        Dim projList As List(Of projection) = (From d In projCtx.projections
                                               Where d.Date = requestedDate AndAlso d.ProjectionTypeId = 1
                                               Select d).ToList()
        ' Since symbolIdList is a collection of objects in memory and you cannot join a set of data
        ' in the database with another set of data that is in memory, projList is set up in memory as well
        Dim dvpList As List(Of DataValuePair) = (From d In projList
                   Join e In symbolIdList On e.Id Equals d.SymbolId
                   Select New DataValuePair() With {
                       .Text = e.Name,
                       .Value = e.Id}).OrderBy(Function(o) o.Text).ToList()
        'no .Distinct() needed here as we are doing that when the two objects in memory are created

        For x As Integer = 1 To dvpList.Count
            ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem(dvpList(x - 1).Text, dvpList(x - 1).Value))
        Next
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select a Commodity", 0))

    End Using
    Return ddl
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably this part:

```
Where symbolTypeList.Contains(d.SymbolType)
```

I don't know about the latest versions of Entity Framework, but versions up to and including 4.0 are notoriously bad at handling `Contains` clauses. I've had [a similar problem myself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3523119/399649). If you only have 3 values to compare it to, try writing it out explicitly:

```
Where d.SymbolType = 17
Or d.SymbolType = 18
Or d.SymbolType = 19
```

I don't see anything else in your code that's likely to cause the error message you posted.

Comment: both symbolIdList and projList get populated correctly. Its something in the dvpList query itself that's causing the issue.

Comment: The answer is the .Distinct() needs to be removed from the query since I am already getting distinct projection values in projList variable. That is what was causing the error.